# org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to run Spring application with Hibernate on Wildly 13.

This is my POM configuration:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I deploy the package I get this error:

```
   deployment.datalis_db.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:201)
            ... 62 more
        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ba87c15
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:547)
            at deployment.datalis_db.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:73)
            ... 63 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ba87c15.<init>()
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3302)
```

Full log with error stack:
https://pastebin.com/fXSE1k7t

Do I need to exclude some dependency in my POM file?
Can you give e some advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: A few of those dependencies should likely be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`. Also Servlet 4.0 is only available if you enable Java EE 8 preview mode, by passing `-Dee8.preview.mode=true`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please make official answer with your recommendations? I would like to up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

A few of those dependencies should likely be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`. For example `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api`, both the JAXB API and implementation and `javax.activation:acitivation` should definitely be marked as provided.

Also Servlet 4.0 is only available if you enable Java EE 8 preview mode, by passing `-Dee8.preview.mode=true`. This can be passed on the command like when you launch the server, be placed as a system property in the configuration or added to the `JAVA_OPTS`.